# How to test Apache Kafka for multiple clients?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I've created one producer and consumer script each to publish and receive data from topic. But how can I do the same for multiple clients? I'm using Node JS for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question need a bit more of explanation but maybe you can find what you are looking for [here](https://medium.com/@ashok.tankala/kafka-consumer-group-and-batch-producer-in-node-js-cd144727615c)

Can you please try to describe a bit more your issue ?